# Why does _execv put processes in background on Windows?

Tags: c, cmd, mingw, exec, errorlevel

Consider this wrapper:

```
/*
    build using

        x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o ping_wrapper.exe ping_wrapper.c
*/


#include <process.h>

#define REAL_EXECUTABLE "C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\PING.EXE"

int main(int const argc, char const * argv[])
{
    argv[0] = REAL_EXECUTABLE;
    _execv(REAL_EXECUTABLE, argv);
    abort();
}
```

Now if I run `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\PING.EXE` from the command line, I get the usage message and a subsequent `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` prints 1 because I had a usage error.

But if I run this `ping_wrapper.exe` I have to press Enter after the usage message and a subsequent `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` prints 0.

Same if I ping `1.1.1.1`: When I press Ctrl-C the original drops me back to the prompt, but the wrapper requires Enter.

Also if I use the wrapper in a batch file, the wrapper runs in the background. (The script continues without waiting for the wrapper to exit.)

I would have expected that the wrapper behaves exactly like the original. This is the case with Unix' `execv`. What is happening here?

Comment: How does your title match anything in the body. The word *background* isn't mentioned at all in the body.

Comment: @CatCat Edit: Now it is.